# android tcp socket データ送受信について

Tags: android, tcp, socket, udp

androidを勉強しております。
この記事のudpの部分を見て
http://asnet.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/07/27/100237
この記事のsocketを見て
https://qiita.com/sourcekatu/items/3501d421a6c3a4a2be17
ホストとゲストのandroidで片方からipをブロードキャストして、もう片方が受け取り、そのip
に向けてメッセージを送信して、受け取った方は受信することができました。
質問なのですが、双方向にデータをやりとりしたいのですが、 
`socket = Socket()

socket!!.connect(ipadress)`
このコードを実行するのはゲスト側なのですが、このコードは、一方向にデータを送信するもので、ゲストはホストに一方向にデータを送りつけることはできて、ホストからのデータを受信するときは、ホスト側でも同じような処理をする必要があるということですか？？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socketを2つ作る必要はありません。

`Socket`は双方向に通信できるので、それぞれで

```
socket.getOutputStream()
socket.getInputStream()
```

すれば、1つのソケットで送受信できます。